# Twitter Advanced Search not showing results

Tags: twitter

I am trying to do a simple twitter adv search query where I want to find tweets tweeted by "@BSE_News" and that contain some word like for example "Financial". However, twitter's search doesn't show any tweet and there are tons of tweets that are tweeted by  [BSE_News](https://twitter.com/BSE_News) that contain this word.

What I am doing currently -

1. Go to the advanced search section once I have logged into my twitter a/c
2. I enter "Financial" in the "This exact phrase" text box and "@BSE_News" in the "From these accounts" text box. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I confirm this is not normal. You should ask Twitter on their forum : https://twittercommunity.com . Even a simple search "from:@BSE_News" returns nothing. Maybe too much tweets ?

Comment: Ok, I have done that. Lets see what I get back. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I can confirm that with the API "statuses/user_timeline" you get tweets from @BSE_News but not with "search/tweets"

Comment: Yes, that is what was suggested on the twitter forum as well. But honestly, if you ask me the search should work. I mean there is nothing I am asking the search to do which is out of the ordinary. The workaround for me is going to be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twitter's advanced search boolean operators, coupled with the advanced search operator `from:` to construct the following query (you can copy & paste it into Twitter's search box or type it directly there):

`(financial) from:BSE_News`

Of course, you can also broaden or narrow your search by playing with the boolean statement in between the parenthesis using the `OR`, `AND`, `-`(minus for NOT) and `(` `)` boolean combinations. For example:

`(financial OR economic OR monetary OR fiscal) from:BSE_News`

`(financial AND 2019) from:BSE_News`

`((financial AND PODDAR) -quarter) from:BSE_News`

Answer (score -2):

I guess with the advanced search...some functionalities were disabled, like you don't have the sentiments section anymore

Comment: Please use the comments section to provide guesses or opinions on the OP's question. If you think your answer solves the issue, you should provide some code or screenshots to evaluate your answer.